# boarding flight at intermediate stop

Tags: air-travel, stopovers, hidden-city-ticketing

Suppose I book a flight ticket from place A to place B. This flight has a stop at place C.

Is it possible/allowed for me to board the flight at place C instead of place A?

If it is necessary, place A is Edinburgh, place C is London, place B is Bengaluru.

Comment: As previously asked at *[Do you have to take the second leg of a domestic flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440)*, the answer is no, you cannot. This is true regardless of which segments are domestic or international. If you are a no-show for any flight, then all subsequent flights on the ticket will be canceled automatically. If you wish to board at London, you must contact the airline prior to check-in to have your ticket changed, possibly paying a change fee and fare difference in the process.

Comment: The linked question is different and has a different answer, so I disagree with the decision to mark it as duplicate.  This question is about whether you have to take the *first* leg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

When you fail to board your flight at A, the airline will cancel your entire itinerary, and will not allow you to board at C unless you buy a new ticket.

If you wish to fly only from C to B, then you should contact the airline in advance and change your booking.  The cost of this depends on the airline's policies and the type of ticket you purchased.  Typically it will be at least the difference in fare between your original ticket and a new ticket C-B, possibly plus some change fee.  (If C-B is cheaper than A-C-B, you may be eligible for a partial refund or voucher toward a future flight; however, in some cases, C-B may be [more expensive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5408/why-is-a-nonstop-flight-sometimes-more-expensive-than-multiple-connections) even though it's shorter.)